# Defining a function of an object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object

How do you define a function that is within an object?

```
var CustomerDB = {customers:[], addresses:[], stores:[], insertData, addCustomer}

CustomerDB.insertData = function (objData){
    objData.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.type == "customer"){
        CustomerDB.addCustomer(element.data);
    };
    });
};


CustomerDB.addcustomer = function (customerObj){
    customerObj.add_date= new Date();
    CustomerDB.customers.push(customerObj);
};

CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
console.log(CustomerDB.customers);
```

I keep getting errors that insertData is not defined. What do I need to do?

Comment: `var CustomerDB = {customers:[], addresses:[], stores:[]}`

Comment: how does the program know the function belongs to the object CustomerDB if I don't declare the method in the object?

Comment: You already do: `CustomerDB.insertData = function (objData){...`. Problem was you were trying to do shorthand for `CustomerDB.insertData = insertData; CustomerDB.addCustomer = addCustomer;` but `insertData` and `addCustomer` aren't variables.

Answer (score 0):

`insertData` and `addCustomer` are properties of the CustomerDB object, and are not [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) that you could assign to CustomerDB just like you have tried. If you remove those two technically undefined variables (the interpreter only knows addCustomer and insertData as properties of CustomerDB currently) from CustomerDB, `insertData` and `addCustomer`, then it will work fine:

```
var CustomerDB = {customers:[], addresses:[], stores:[]}

CustomerDB.insertData = function (objData){
    objData.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.type == "customer"){
        CustomerDB.addCustomer(element.data);
    };
    });
};


CustomerDB.addCustomer = function (customerObj){
    customerObj.add_date= new Date();
    CustomerDB.customers.push(customerObj);
};

CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
console.log(CustomerDB.customers);
```

The alternative way using functions assigned to variables:

```
var insertData = function(objData) {
    objData.forEach(function(element){
      if (element.type == "customer"){
        CustomerDB.addCustomer(element.data);
      };
    });
};


var addCustomer = function(customerObj) {
    customerObj.add_date= new Date();
    CustomerDB.customers.push(customerObj);
};

var CustomerDB = {customers:[], addresses:[], stores:[], insertData, addCustomer}

CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
console.log(CustomerDB.customers);
```

One final tidbit: this is ES5 syntax, and I'd strongly encourage you to explore [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants)

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

``

### Rewrite your code as shown below

```js
var CustomerDB = {customers:[], addresses:[], stores:[]}

CustomerDB.insertData = function (objData){
    objData.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.type == "customer"){
    CustomerDB.customers.push(element.data);
    };
    });
};
CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
console.log(CustomerDB.customers);
```

Comment: "Rewrite your code as shown below" - care to explain why?